# Copy JSON column in Redshift

Tags: json, copy, amazon-redshift

I have to import a csv file in redshift from s3.
One of the columns in the table is JSON format.

While using COPY command, I get the following error -

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS]
```

The command used is -

```
COPY api_log FROM 's3://X/Y' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=' delimiter ',' maxerror as 250 TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
```

COMMIT;

Sample data is -

```
c1 c2    c3

  X       Y     {a:b,c:d}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add quotes to the json and `REMOVEQUOTES` to the copy then it works.

Put test file in s3:

```
echo x,y,'"{a:b,c:d}"' | aws s3 cp - s3://[bucket]/json/test_file.csv
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS api_log
(c1 varchar,
c2 varchar,
json_colum varchar(65535));
```

Load:

```
COPY api_log 
FROM 's3://[bucket]/json/' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
delimiter ',' 
maxerror as 250 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS
REMOVEQUOTES;
```

Or, if you don't like quotes, you can use tabs or some other character that will not be in the data.  E.g.:

```
echo -e "x\ty\t{a:b,c:d}" | aws s3 cp - s3://[bucket]/json/test_file.csv
```

Then:

```
COPY api_log 
FROM 's3://[bucket]/json/' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
delimiter '\t' 
maxerror as 250 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS
REMOVEQUOTES;
```

Either way, you get:

```
select * from api_log;
 c1 | c2 | json_colum 
----+----+------------
 x  | y  | {a:b,c:d}
```